# Conditional execution with OOP

Tags: oop, pascal

So, i'm looking for the right way of implementing next thing.
An example, i have parent class for anything. I'm storing variable that are object of that parent-class.

I want to conditionally make this variable object of child-class.

I know how i can implement the following thing with some of other way(just because here are many approaches), but i want good way, so my code will look something like that

```
TObject obj;
if something = 1 then 
   obj := Child1;
else if something = 2 then 
   obj := Child2;
```

Finally, in my task i want to call for some function that are part of parent class, and can(or not) be implemented in child class.

UPD :

I find the best solution(as far as i see) by myself ot looks like:

```
var obj : TParent;
  case something of
    1: obj := TChild1.Create;
    2: obj := TChild2.Create;
```

Comment: At first, I thought you were asking about something that is already part of the object-oriented paradigm (namely, polymorphism), but your phrasing is confusing and I'm not really sure my first guess is correct any more. Presently I'm voting to put this on hold as "Unclear what you are asking". Please feel free to edit your question to elaborate on what specifically you've got in mind.

Comment: Your question seems very unclear, because it sounds (as @AndriyM says) like you're asking about basic polymorphism. Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23349518), which shows an actual compilable/runnable example of basic inheritance and polymorphism, will help. If that's not what you're referring to, please [edit] your question to make it more clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, if that is the kind of a solution you were really looking for, your question had nothing to do with OOP, but instead you were asking about how to do branching in Pascal (efficiently/concisely/whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Make something an object with a method that returns the proper child.

Answer (score 1):

Use principles of object orientation.  You will have a parent class, and some child classes whuch inherit from the parent. Use  overriding for child specific  variables and functionality. If there is functionality that is applicable to all child classes, or the parent, then implement this in the parent.